# How can I keep track of the positions/indices of my elements in a minimum heap?

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, heap, priority-queue

```
heap = MinHeap()
print(heap) #[]
heap.push(5)
print(heap) #[5]
heap.push(1)
print(heap) #[1,5]
heap.push(4)
print(heap) #[1,5,4]
heap.push(20)
print(heap) #[1,5,4,20]
heap.push(2)
print(heap) #[1,2,4,20,5]
```

How could I constantly track of the index positions of each item in my minimum heap every time an item is served or pushed into the minimum heap? Can the complexity of this be achieved in O(1) time complexity?

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you please be more precise about the expected output and what you've tried to reach it?

Comment: Are you assuming then that values in the heap will be unique?

Answer (score 0):

If you have your own MinHeap implementation, then add a dictionary attribute to it (like `self._dict`), with the keys being the values in the heap, and the values being their positions (indexes).

So where you currently assign (move, swap,...) a value to a certain index, like with `self.arr[i] = val`, then you should also do `self._dict[val] = i`.

For this to work as expected, you would need to ensure that values in the heap are unique. If not, then add to your implementation a frequency counter, and don't store the same value twice at separate indexes.